# How to use set_yticks with ax.loglog

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, loglog, yticks

Using matplotlib, I want to eliminate the yticks and ytick labels from a loglog plot. It works for a regular plot, but not for loglog.

The following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([2,4],[8,10])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

gives a desirable result.

[ax.plot allows removal of both xticks and yticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zEZY.png)

But if instead I want loglog scaling, it fails.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog([2,4],[8,10])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[for ax.loglog, ax.set_xticks([]) and  does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBGLC.png)

I have tried multiple different fixes, and nothing seems to work. I have a more complicated example where

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xvals=np.logspace(-1,1,20)
yvals1=np.array([0.03950564, 0.03953078, 0.03957078, 0.03962743, 0.03970915,
       0.03981691, 0.03994918, 0.04010086, 0.04026356, 0.04042849,
       0.04058817, 0.04073742, 0.04087351, 0.04099616, 0.04110702,
       0.04120875, 0.04130422, 0.04139636, 0.04148823, 0.04158317])
yvals2=np.array([0.0223383 , 0.02247799, 0.02265306, 0.02287054, 0.02314318,
       0.0234758 , 0.02387278, 0.02434108, 0.02489343, 0.02555092,
       0.02634133, 0.02729466, 0.02843651, 0.02978005, 0.03131751,
       0.03301349, 0.03480207, 0.03658879, 0.03825972, 0.03970347])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3 , figsize = (15,5))
axs[0].loglog(xvals,yvals1,c = 'green')
axs[0].loglog(xvals,yvals2,c = 'tab:blue')
axs[0].set_ylim(0.02,0.07)
axs[0].set_xlim(0.1,10)
axs[0].set_xticks([])
axs[0].set_yticks([])
axs[1].loglog(xvals,yvals1,c = 'green')
axs[1].loglog(xvals,yvals2,c = 'tab:blue')
axs[1].set_ylim(0.02,0.07)
axs[1].set_xlim(0.1,10)
axs[1].set_xticks([])
axs[1].set_yticks([])
axs[2].loglog(xvals,yvals1,c = 'green')
axs[2].loglog(xvals,yvals2,c = 'tab:blue')
axs[2].set_ylim(0.02,0.07)
axs[2].set_xlim(0.1,10)
axs[2].set_xticks([])
axs[2].set_yticks([])
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
```

[ax.loglog can remove xticks but not yticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9kdB.png)

My third example is closer to the actual code I am trying to run (I have changed the x and y values).

I have tried many things, including changing order of function calls, using the set_yticklabels() function, setting labels=None, setting major=False and minor=False etc.

What I am expecting when calling

`ax.set_yticks([])`

is to see tick *marks* , but no tick labels. I want to eliminate the numbers on the side of the plots.

Comment: `plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)` is one way

Comment: There are apparently many ways of removing ticks, which work depending on the format of the axis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off the `major` x|y ticks AND the `minor` x|y ticks as well

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
ax.loglog((1,10000), (1,10000))
ax.set_xticks([1, 100, 10000]) ; ax.set_xticks([], minor=1)
ax.set_yticks([]) ; ax.set_yticks([], minor=1)
plt.show()
```